# Angular 2, localhost/null error when trying to use http.get?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular

I am using Angular 2 to make a webpage. When I load the page, I use OnInit to run the following method (with generic names substituted):

```
getAllObjects(): Promise<object[]>{
    return this.http.get(this.getAllObjectsUrl).toPromise().then(response => response.json().data).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

I've verified in my browser that the getAllObjects url does indeed return an array of `object` in JSON format. Here is the url if it is helpful:

```
private getAllObjectsUrl : 'http://99.240.124.235:7060/REST/rest/companyService/getAllCompanies.json/';
```

However, this method triggers the handleError catch and the browser's debugging log shows `GET localhost:3000/null 404 NOT FOUND` (I am using an npm server to run it, hence the localhost).

I do not believe it is a CORS issue because I downloaded the Chrome CORS plugin and other API calls have worked. It is only this particular API url that is causing a problem, which I find strange as my other API calls work and they follow the exact same format (except a different url).

I thought maybe the `appComponent` wasn't allowed an OnInit, but I replaced `getAllObjects()` with a different working API call, and I didn't receive this error.

I am completely stuck and any help would be appreciated (could this error be because of the web API, not the front end?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getAllObjectsUrl doesn't contain the url because you are using colon(:) instead of equal sign(=)

Colon indicates the type of the variable, whereas equal sign initializes it.

change this

```
private getAllObjectsUrl : 'http://99.240.124.235:7060/REST/rest/companyService/getAllCompanies.json/';
```

for this

```
private getAllObjectsUrl = 'http://99.240.124.235:7060/REST/rest/companyService/getAllCompanies.json/';
```

Comment: That is embarrassing... I don't know why I used a colon for this one url, or how I didn't see that... thanks...